# Stub Postgresql JSON type with HSQLDB

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, unit-testing, spring-boot, hsqldb

I am looking for a way to stub Postgresql JSON type in HSQLDB. I need it for unit testing.

Specifying a JDBC URL parameter `sql.syntax_pgs=true` does not work so I created a `schema-hsqdbl.sql` script which Spring Boot picks up automatically upon start.

I tried to stub this type in following ways.

```
DROP TYPE json IF EXISTS;
CREATE TYPE json AS varbinary(1000000);

DROP TYPE json IF EXISTS;
CREATE TYPE json AS binary;

DROP TYPE json IF EXISTS;
CREATE TYPE json AS text;

DROP TYPE json IF EXISTS;
CREATE TYPE json AS other;
```

Unfortunately all of that fails upon persisting an instance of my entity with

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: incompatible data type in operation
```

For a real mapping into Postgresql JSON I use the Vlad Mihalcea's [solution](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-json-objects-using-generic-hibernate-types/)

Comment: You may also try CREATE TYPE json AS OTHER;

Comment: Nope, unfortunately the same error.

Comment: It turns out that the exception is thrown in the JDBC driver, because `JsonNode` does not implement `Serializable` interface which is checked against for the [java.sql.Types.OTHER](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Types.html#OTHER).